# Behaviour of $\mathrm{argmin}_{\theta} \mathbb{E}_X \left[|X-\theta|^q\right]$ as $q \to 0^+$

Tags: probability

I have heard that $\mathrm{argmin}_{\theta} \mathbb{E}_X \left[|X-\theta|^q\right]$ should approach the mode of the probability distribution as $q \to 0^+$. Intuitively this makes sense to me: $\lim_{q \to 0^+} | \theta - x|^q = 1$ everywhere except where $x =\theta$ in which case it is zero. Knowing this when solving the minimisation problem for very small $q$ we want to to cancel out the tallest part of the probability distribution by multiplying by $0$. However I have been at a complete loss when attempting to prove anything close to this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: coud you be more specific? You want to find $f(q)$ satisfying  $v(q) = \theta + \mathcal{O}(f(q))$ where $v(q) = \mathrm{argmin}_{\theta} \mathbb{E}_X \left[|X-\theta|^q\right]$ ?

Comment: I wish to find $\lim_{q \to 0^+} \mathrm{argmin}_{\theta} \mathbb{E}_X \left[ | X - \theta |^q \right] $